# Transfer files & Message Passing from One System to remote System using Internet

Tags: delphi, indy10

Which one is (TCP/UDP) best to send files from Client to Remote server using Internet? i.e Which one is fast & reliable of my following requirement.

I have two requirements basically

```
1. Sending Files from Client to Server (Daily Once)
2. In Client system running one software, its having different product information, 
   latest packet Time, Product Status, etc . 
   This information is updated every one second. 
   My problem is, To know the Client status at server.

 I am not able to decided which design is best of my requirement. They are
   A.Using TIdTCPClient & TIdTCPServer 
   B.Using TIdTCPClient & TIdCmdTCPServer
   C.Using TIdCmdClient & TIdTCPServer
   D.Using TIdCmdClient & TIdCMDTCPServer
```

Please guide to me which design is best & how to implement it with example.

Comment: You can also use TIdHTTP and TIdHTTPServer to upload files and other information. HTTP has some advantages over ad-hoc protocol implementations - content-length header, authentication, firewall-friendliness, widely supported and understood etc.

Comment: Yes your correct but one point is **HTTP file transfering is slower than TCP**. After I had test it was decided to use TCP. One more limitation is file size limit.  It was support upto 4.5MB but in my case file sizes are more than 5MB to 10MB. Also we can use FTP but some clients are working behind Proxys & Firewall.

Answer (score 0):

TCP/IP is slower but it assures you that you don't lose any packet without implementing that in your application

UDP is faster but you don't have the guarantee that the packet will arrive and you must implement some sort of confirmation

In your situation i think TCP is the best and TIdTCPClient with TIdTCPServer will do the trick.

Post some code if you get stuck.